# Counting recurring letters in a string with python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
word = 'monsoon'

def check(x):
    emptyList = []
    search = list(word)
    for element in x:
        count_elements = str(search.count(element))
        emptyList += count_elements
        
    print(emptyList)

check(word)
```

I am trying to count all the occurrences of each letter in the word and return it in a list, however I get ['1', '3', '2', '1', '3', '3', '2'] which kind of works but I want to avoid counting the same letter twice so I should have ['1', '3', '2', '1'] as the answer, how can I go about this?

Comment: `from collections import Counter         Counter('monsoon')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary object for that:

```
word = 'monsoon'

def check(x):
   count = {letter:x.count(letter) for letter in x}
   print(count)

check(word)
```

Dictionary in python saves values as `key:value` pairs and does not allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Using comprehension on the dictionary just to set it to 0 is a huge waste.  If you are going to do that you might as well do `count = {letter:x.count(letter) for letter in x}` and be done.

Comment: Keep in mind this is an O(n^2) solution (to be fair, so is OP's attempt)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to modify your existing code much, you can iterate over a set of the elements in your word which means each one will only be counted once

```
word = 'monsoon'

def check(x):
    emptyList = []
    search = list(word)
    for element in set(x):
        count_elements = str(search.count(element))
        emptyList += count_elements
        
    print(emptyList)

check(word)
```

gives

`['2', '3', '1', '1']`

Note that the order is not preserved since sets are unordered so you may want to return a different data structure if that's important